# Strip in a map returns the strip

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, strip

```
'a.x'.strip('.x')
```

returns `'a'` but

```
f = ['a.x', 'b.x']
m = map(lambda it: str.strip('.x'), f)
list(m)
```

returns `['.x', '.x']`.

How do I get `map` to return `['a', 'b']`?

Comment: Also `[it.strip('.x') for it in f]` is an option

Answer (score 2):

`str` is a python class. Calling `str.strip('.x')` is equivalent to calling `'.x'.strip()` where `'.x'` is passed as the self parameter. Instead you should be doing:

```
it.strip('.x')
```

Comment: That's great. Thank  you!